# Why does the RX interrupt trigger, when there is no data on the RX pin?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, avr

On my embedded device, I've got port hooked up to my UART. The functionality is working, I can RX/TX fine. The odd thing is, I've got a pin on that port set as an input for debugging. When there is no data on the RX/TX line, but I pulse that debug pin, it actually tiggers the ISR for the RX interrupt.

Any ideas on why this could happen?

Comment: Noise? Crosstalk?  Can you put a scope on the debug pin & the RX line and see?

Comment: Heh - triple-check your interrupt-controller initialization too.

Comment: Can you post the device part number, what pins you are using and the code you use to initialise the UART?

Comment: Ground RX and see if it still triggers?

Comment: It seemed like the pin that I was using was connected to an external interrupt on the AVR. I wrote a ISR for handling it to see if it would still trigger the RX vector, which seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: While it seems like it wasn't an issue, an internal or external pullup on a UART RX line can help it avoid trying to respond to noise - in addition to the power consumption advantages of not having floating inputs.